# BeautifulSoup - unable to extract data by id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract instrument price using python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    instrument = "us100"
    get_price(instrument)

def get_price(instrument):
    url = "https://www.xtb.com/pl/oferta/dostepne-rynki/indeksy/{}".format(instrument)
    page_content = requests.get(url)
    parsed_page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_content.content, "html.parser")
    print(parsed_page_content.find("span", {"id": "bid"}))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but as result i receive:
main.py
None

what i'm doing wrong? :)

Comment: there is no span element with that id.

Comment: when I'm browsing through webpage html code i see : <div class="box-bid">
                        <p class="title"> Sprzedaj </p>
                        <span id="bid">11837.<strong>27</strong></span>
                    </div>

Comment: Yah I see that too... That means they are probably updating it through an ajax call of some kind.

Comment: any idea how to extract this? ( and to be sure - my code is OK? )

Comment: Instead of beautifulsoup, you'll probably have to use Selenium, as it will actually load the page in a browser. You can use the WebDriverWait class to make it wait until the expected element appears on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requests.get() won't get any content that is dynamically loaded into the webpage, such as that price info which is constantly updating. As a result, beautifulsoup isn't useful here.
You can use Selenium along with the webdriver for your browser of choice to launch the browser window, get the info and automatically close the browser.

Here's a quick solution I hacked up.  I used MS Edge because I  didn't currently have the updated webdriver for the version of Chrome I have installed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

instrument = "us100"

edgeService = Service("C:\Drivers\webdrivers\msedgedriver.exe")
edgeService.start()
edgeDriver = webdriver.Remote(edgeService.service_url)
edgeDriver.get("https://www.xtb.com/pl/oferta/dostepne-rynki/indeksy/{}".format(instrument))

WebDriverWait(edgeDriver, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".box-bid")
            )
    )

priceelement = edgeDriver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".box-bid")
print(priceelement)
span = priceelement.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#bid")
print(span)
print(span.text)
print(span.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
edgeDriver.stop_client()
edgeService.stop()
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a6b6bec2ea3d781566cb321e929d2b2", element="eef454c1-f414-4bcb-815e-8ef36712d8c4")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9a6b6bec2ea3d781566cb321e929d2b2", element="48d6c6d7-b3e2-42f0-a28b-0441998da99a")>
11662.02
11662.<strong>02</strong>
```

Comment: thank you, needed to calibrate timeouts, but it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_driver_path = Service(Your_Driver_Path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://www.xtb.com/pl/indeksy-gieldowe")

span_id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="bid"]').text
```